# Group by - Need to display on single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema setup :

table name : `thing`

```
Column | type
----------------------------
id     | auto increment int
ident  | int
cost1  | int
cost2  | int
cost3  | int
```

table name : `thing_usage`

```
column     | type
---------------------------------
id         | auto increment int
thing      | int - FK to thing.id
usage_type | int
data       | int
duration   | int
```

with some data :

`thing` :

```
id    | ident    | cost1    | cost2   | cost3
------------------------------------------------
1     | 1234     | 1        | 2       | 3
2     | 5678     | 0        | 0       | 0
```

`thing_usage` :

```
id    | thing     | usage_type  |  data    | duration
--------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1         | 1           | 5555     | 0
2     | 1         | 1           | 3        | 0
3     | 1         | 2           | 0        | 123
4     | 1         | 3           | 232      | 12
```

All available here -> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ed38)

What I would like to output if a single row for each `thing` like this :

```
thing   | cost1   | usage1   | cost2   | usage2   | cost3   | usage3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1       | 5558     | 2       | 00:02:03 | 3       | 232
2       | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0
```

`cost1` uses `usage_type` of `1`, `cost2` uses `usage_type` of `2` and so on ...... and  `cost1` and `cost3` use `data` for its usage and `cost2` converts `duration` from seconds to hh:mm:ss for usage - usage should be summed

At the moment i have to create 2 queries and so this in code - so i loop all `thing` rows then get the usage for it and output accordingly

Is there any way that I can get the desired output from a single query - perhaps using a subquery of some kind?

Comment: This is called a "pivot" or a "pivot table".  Try a google search for "msql pivot example".

Comment: @dwb thanks - i will take a look ... i did struggle to call it something ! now i know

Comment: I'd give an answer, but I have to google it every time because I so seldom do pivots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you were looking for:

```
SELECT thing_usage1.id
  ,thing.id
  ,thing.cost1
  ,SUM(thing_usage1.data) AS usage1
  ,thing.cost2
  ,TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(thing_usage2.duration),'%H:%i:%s') AS usage2
  ,thing.cost3
  ,SUM(thing_usage3.data) AS usage3
FROM thing AS thing
INNER JOIN thing_usage AS thing_usage1 ON thing.id = thing_usage1.thing
  AND thing.cost1 = thing_usage1.usage_type
INNER JOIN thing_usage AS thing_usage2 ON thing.id = thing_usage2.thing
  AND thing.cost2 = thing_usage2.usage_type
INNER JOIN thing_usage AS thing_usage3 ON thing.id = thing_usage3.thing
  AND thing.cost3 = thing_usage3.usage_type
GROUP BY thing_usage1.id
  ,thing.id
  ,thing.cost1
  ,thing.cost2
  ,thing.cost3
```

Here is an example of it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68f430/51

Updated my logic to account for the `SUM`ming piece, as well as the use of duration.

Comment: Almost ... the second `thing` is missing .. and ive just updated my question as i need to sum the usage ... Sorry and the cost doesnt equal the usage_type - the `cost1` value could be 1000 and still use `usage1`

Comment: Updated my logic and example link to account for the `SUM` components.

Comment: But what if cost1 is 100 ... and what about the 0 usage rows ?

Comment: im failing to understand the question ... im trying to glean what these values mean based on your explanation, but you give no context to the data. you talk about summing items and provide timestamps ... please provide a more detailed explanation of the problem and you will get a more accurate answer.

Comment: The `thing` table is like an invoice - it contains the cost for usage. The `cost1` field contains the cost of usage where `usage_type` = 1. What i am trying to do is produce a report that shows the usage and cost on the same row ... hope that helps a little - i think im pretty close using your answer as a starter -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ed38/6 ive added in some more data but it seem the sum of duration takes in usage_type of 1 too ...

Comment: I've updated my logic to attempt accounting for your duration component ... hopefully that is what you were going for (converting seconds into a time). I tried to make it ANSI-compliant (still looking), but I was forced to use proprietary methods to get the duration piece.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it "manually" here is something to get you started:

```
SELECT
th.ident,
th.cost1,
SUM(tu.data) as usage1data
FROM
thing th
JOIN thing_usage tu
ON th.id = tu.thing
WHERE tu.usage_type = 1
GROUP BY th.id, tu.usage_type
```

And this query should get you going on collecting all sums in one statement:

```
SELECT
tu.thing,
    SUM(CASE WHEN usage_type=1 THEN tu.data ELSE 0 END) AS usage1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN usage_type=2 THEN tu.data ELSE 0 END) AS usage2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN usage_type=3 THEN tu.data ELSE 0 END) AS usage3
FROM 
    thing_usage tu
```

Comment: But thats only going to get me one of the usage types ?

Comment: @ManseUK Obviously, yes. You could take it from there and extend this solution to the other columns. I will add another hint.